# Sending an SNS Notification when Alarm state changes to OK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I have monitored the status of VPN tunnels in my account.I have created CloudWatch alarms and configured SNS notifications when they are down.
At the moment, that is working fine. Now, I have got another requirement saying I have to send alarm whenever the state changes to OK.

This is the image of the alarm configuration :

[image]

There, in the snapshot, it says :

**Whenever this alarm : STATE is ALARM**

I would change that to :

**Whenever this alarm : STATE is OK**

But, by doing that, will the Cloud Watch send me notifications every 5 minutes until the state is in OK? 
I have this doubt because it is written STATE is OK instead of STATE changes to OK.
Please let me know.

Comment: Hey can you help me with , How you implement this ALARM --> Ok 

I have done this for my task but it also sending Notification for INSUFFICIENT_DATA --> OK, but I want only for ALARM--> OK

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An Amazon CloudWatch alarm only sends a notification on a **change of state**.

So, if your alarm is set to send a notification when State = OK: If the state is already OK, it will *not* send a notification. However, when the state changes to something *else* and the changes back to OK, it would send a notification.

Comment: Hey can you help me with , How to implement this ALARM --> Ok 

I have done this for my task but it also sending Notification for INSUFFICIENT_DATA --> OK, but I want only for ALARM--> OK